# Repeat values from a sequence up to n

Tags: python, list, numpy

Say I want to repeat a sequence of consecutive `0`s and `1`s up to `n`. One way I can think of is:

```
seq = np.array([0,1])
a = np.tile(seq, math.ceil(n/2))[:n]
```

Where I use `math.ceil(n/2)` so that only an extra number is generated in the case of having an odd `n`. But is there a more concise way of doing this? This should ideally be extendable to any given sequence, for example:

```
n = 6
seq = np.array([1,2,3,4])
np.tile(seq, math.ceil(n/2))[:n]
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.resize` may work for you.

```
In [43]: seq = np.array([1,2,3,4])
In [44]: np.resize(seq, 6)
Out[44]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2])
```

We don't use `resize` (function or method) that often, but in this case the fill pattern for the function version meets your needs.

Comment: Nice :) Didn't know it repeated it if the new size is greater

Comment: The `.resize` method behaves differently.